# Deleted Linux partition - how do I make Windows boot normally?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub

I just deleted the Linux partition. As far as I know that volume also contained GRUB and when that's installed it overwrites the Windows boot record. How do I make Windows boot again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This eHow article should help you:

> How to repair MBR on Windows 7:
>   http://www.ehow.com/how_4836283_repair-mbr-windows.html

From that article:

> 1. Insert Win 7 installation DVD and boot
>      from DVD drive. While in some older
>      systems you may have to change boot
>      order through system BIOS, most newer
>      systems allow booting from DVD without
>      changing boot order by simply clicking
>      on any key when prompted to doing so.
> 2. Choose your default "Language",
>      "Time", and "keyboard Input" on the
>      first window and click next.
> 3. You're
>      now presented with 3 choices. Click on
>      "Repair Your Computer" to gain access
>      to the System Recovery window. Now
>      choose "Command Prompt" in order to
>      run the desired utility which is
>      called "bootsect.exe". Bootsect is
>      located inside the boot folder so
>      change your directory to boot. Now run
>      "bootsect /nt60 C:\" if you had Win 7
>      initially installed in the C
>      partition. Alternatively, you can run
>      "bootsect /nt60 SYS" or "bootsect
>      /nt60 ALL" to repair the system
>      partition or all partitions. Eject the
>      DVD, and restart computer. Your
>      computer should now boot Win 7 again.

Comment: I don't have a win-7 disk atm, is this possible to fix from within windows?

Comment: If you can get your hands on the bootsect utility normally found on the DVD, you may be able to run ` bootsect /nt60 C:\ ` from inside Windows (as an administrator).

Comment: @Gjorgji: You may also have the option to create a system repair disc: ` All Programs > Maintenance > Create a System Repair Disc `

Comment: It's saying bootsect is not a recognised command when trying it run it from command prompt

Comment: I did say "If you can get your hands on [it]". @Gjorgji

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```